# My Mat-Select with multiple option is not updating correctly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to create a `Mat-Select` which allows multiple choices and which also uses `Option Groups`. The idea is to have nested options with selectable groups.
For example, in my case I am listing jobs assigned to different teams. I would like to be able to either select specific jobs or else all jobs assigned to a team by selecting the Team.

I am using a Reactive form component and although I should be assigning the value correctly to the `inputControl` the display is never updated, i.e. the checkboxes of the selected elements are never updated.

Here is my html code:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Jobs</mat-label>
  <mat-select multiple>
    <mat-optgroup *ngFor="let group of teams" >
      <mat-checkbox
      (change)="onSelectTeam($event, group)"
      >
        {{group.team.name}}
      </mat-checkbox>

      <mat-option *ngFor="let job of group.jobs" [value]="job">
        {{projectIndex[job].name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-optgroup>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

This is my .ts code:

```js
inputFormControl = new FormControl();

  teams = [
    {
      team: {
        id: "e4a3661f-a20b-4720-8c19-2e836821c267",
        code: "T1A",
        name: "Test Team A"
      },
      jobs: [
        "757c7218-4151-4b95-ac21-d9693c6b0e3d",
        "642c0226-d4a6-4a20-9cbb-29eaf90b35a8"
      ]
    },
    {
      team: {
        id: "d9d367aa-6b3d-4990-b227-b54a7324292c",
        code: "T2A",
        name: "Test Team B"
      },
      jobs: [
        "bb3c32fd-519f-4528-9629-a216819351e7",
        "ffce4587-0805-4f7d-9d32-b158244c9b58",
        "36e6eb29-be0f-432b-a121-62bd71d200e7"
      ]
    }
  ];
  projectIndex = {
    "757c7218-4151-4b95-ac21-d9693c6b0e3d": {
      id: "757c7218-4151-4b95-ac21-d9693c6b0e3d",
      name: "Project 1"
    },
    "642c0226-d4a6-4a20-9cbb-29eaf90b35a8": {
      id: "642c0226-d4a6-4a20-9cbb-29eaf90b35a8",
      name: "Project 2"
    },
    "bb3c32fd-519f-4528-9629-a216819351e7": {
      id: "bb3c32fd-519f-4528-9629-a216819351e7",
      name: "Project 3"
    },
    "ffce4587-0805-4f7d-9d32-b158244c9b58": {
      id: "ffce4587-0805-4f7d-9d32-b158244c9b58",
      name: "Project 4"
    },
    "36e6eb29-be0f-432b-a121-62bd71d200e7": {
      id: "36e6eb29-be0f-432b-a121-62bd71d200e7",
      name: "Project 5"
    }
  };

onSelectTeam(event: any, team: Team): void
  {
    console.log(team);
    let currValue = this.inputFormControl.value;
    currValue = currValue ? currValue : [];
    if (event.checked)
    {
      currValue.push(...team.jobs);
    }
    else {
      team.jobs.forEach(job => currValue.splice(currValue.indexOf(job), 1));
    }
    console.log(this.inputFormControl.value);
    console.log(currValue);
    this.writeValue(currValue);
  }

onChange = (value: any) => {};
onTouched = () => {};

registerOnChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  // Allows Angular to register a function to call when the input has been touched.
  // Save the function as a property to call later here.
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  // Allows Angular to disable the input.
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.disabled = isDisabled;
    if (isDisabled) {
      this.inputFormControl.disable();
    }
  }

  writeValue(obj: any): void
  {
    this.inputFormControl.setValue(obj);
  }

  validate(): ValidationErrors | null {
    if (!this.inputFormControl.valid) {
      return this.inputFormControl.errors;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

The component itself is a custom component so it is using the `ControlValueAccessor`. Would really appreciate if anyone can help me to identify the problem.

Comment: actually managed to sort it out using 2 way data binding on the mat select value!

Answer (score 0):

the issue value is not set at run time on html but shown in console 1st time is null but when you debug its value is shown this issue is because of sync call you have to set the value of variable in that function when you call it
example is ;
this works fine
this.http.post(`${this.bUrl}`, this.user).subscribe(res => {
if (res.toString()) {
localStorage.setItem("tokenVal", res["token"]);
this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
}
});
issue is when you call it like

```
this.http.post(`${this.bUrl}`, this.user).subscribe(res => {
       if (res.toString()) {
         Val = res;
       }
     });
localStorage.setItem("tokenVal", Val["token"]);
this.router.navigate(["/home"]);

similarly you can call it in your function where you are going to set values.
```

Comment: not sure i am understanding what the issue is in my context though? can you specify what i need to change in which function? do you mean i need to use onValueChanges? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am running into a very similar issue with Angular reactive forms and patchValue. When attempting to "check all" on a mat-optgroup by calling patchValue and passing an array of ids, the checkboxes do not visually update.

If I proceed to do the GET call tied to the form, I can see that indeed the "check all" function worked and it passes the ids properly as parameters.

I'm still digging into the issue but I was able to find a work-around by calling patchValue with null directly before the actual call.

```
formGroup.get('FORM_CONTROL').patchValue(null);
formGroup.get('FORM_CONTROL').patchValue(['id1','id2','id3'])
```

Comment: hi @LHB, i actually managed to solve this myself by using two-way data binding. Basically i use an array in the component to store the selections of the mat-select. Then this array is bound to the value of the select. In the writeValue method of the component i am then writing to this array to update the value and it works. Let me know if you want me to share some code